# How to Pass information to pop up modal?

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I am using Boostrap modal. I need to show user information which is fetched form server using PHP and mySql. How do I pass the information to the modal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using data Attribute we can Pass Json Data and then handle that with Javascript or Jequery.

```
<a href="#" data-data="<?php json_encode($variable);?>" />Some Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#modalid").on("show.bs.modal", function (event) {
    $( "#modalbody" ).load( "url/to/script.php");
});
```

Comment: I need to pass only data arrays.. And then i can handle with that

Answer (score 0):

make some hidden variable and assign the values in the model before show event.

```
$("#modal-content").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
  $("#selector").val(your variable value);
});
```

Comment: Not an single value, I need to pass array

Comment: you can call different selectors with arrays values set.